# Regular Expression Negate Colon doesn't work

Tags: java, regex

I have a JSON String which is:

```
{"dependencies":["xz","pkg-config","glib","gobject-introspection"],"conflicts_with":[],"caveats":null,"options":[{"option":"--universal","description":"Build a universal binary"}]}
```

And I wrote a regular expression to find the array behind "dependencies":

```
(?<=\"dependencies\":).*[^:](?=,)
```

in Java:

```
"(?<=\\\"dependencies\\\":).*[^:](?=,)"
```

However the result turns out:

```
["xz","pkg-config","glib","gobject-introspection"],"conflicts_with":[],"caveats":null,"options":[{"option":"--universal"
```

And only the last colon was excluded.

Please help me out.

Comment: Did you try `"(?<=\\\"dependencies\\\":).*?[^:](?=,)"` ?

Comment: @stribizhew yes and it turns out " ["xz" ", It seems like [^:} do not take any effectToT

Comment: And what if you use `(?<=\\\"dependencies\\\":).*?(?=(?<=\\]),)` ?

Comment: `(?<=\"dependencies\":)[^\]]*\]`

Comment: The question is " [^:] " doesn't exclude " ] ". Even that expression returns the "right" result but is not able to be generalized. I want to find the value behind a given key. Not every value is an array so...:P

Comment: Please post the expected result. If you want to exclude `[` and `]`, you can use `(?<=\\\"dependencies\\\":\\[).*?(?=\\],)` regex.

Comment: @SashaSalauyou yes this can also get the right result. But could u please explain why the negation on : doesn't work in my expression?

Comment: @stribizhev The thing is I want to get the value for any given key. The regex I came up with is to find the longest sequences ended with , but is excluded with :. This is what [^:](?=,) supposed to mean. But why the negation on : doesn't work? Many thanks!

Comment: @ChangLi because `.*` part takes as much characters as possible with greedy search turned on by default. `.*[^:]` means "any number of any symbols where not a colon is at the end", for example `abc:bca` satisfies it.

Comment: I guess you wanted `[^:]*` to match any character but `:` any number of times. `.*` is greedy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest using this regex:

```
(?<=\"dependencies\":).[^:]*(?=,)
```

Or, almost equal:

```
(?<=\"dependencies\":)[^:]+(?=,)
```

Comment: However, I think the `.` is unnecessary, it is already matched by `[^:]*`. `(?<=\"dependencies\":)[^:]+(?=,)` is enough. `+` will require at least 1 character in the match.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a non-greedy zero-or-more quantifier:

`(?<=\"dependencies\":)\[(.*?)\]`

This would match `["xz","pkg-config","glib","gobject-introspection"]` in the provided JSON.

Answer (score 0):

This brought to mind [parsing HTML with a regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1509264). Have you tried using a JSON Parser instead?

```
String jsonString = "{\"dependencies\":[\"xz\",\"pkg-config\",\"glib\",\"gobject-introspection\"],\"conflicts_with\":[],\"caveats\":null,\"options\":[{\"option\":\"--universal\",\"description\":\"Build a universal binary\"}]}";
JsonReader jsonReader = Json.createReader(new StringReader( jsonString ));
JsonObject obj = jsonReader.readObject();
jsonReader.close();
String dependencies = obj.getJsonArray( "dependencies" ).toString();
```